# how to make a png image from dynamic text in Android?

Tags: android, png

```
byte[] GetImageFromText(string text, float fontSize)
{
   //do make png image
   //and returns byte array
}
```

I want to get a method like the one above.

Comment: where did you stored your png?

Comment: A png image is stored in memory. and then it will be transferred over the  network.

Comment: Have you converted the image in Base64 form??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this drawing a text view into bitmap first, then you would have to save it as PNG into private app memory or SD card and send it. Here is an exmple how to convert text into bitmap: [How to draw a TextView into a Bitmap (without ever beeing drawn on the display)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298385/how-to-draw-a-textview-into-a-bitmap-without-ever-beeing-drawn-on-the-display/7298528#7298528)

Answer (score 3):

thanks Lumis~

here is my final solution

```
float textSize = 30;
String text = "testing";
TextPaint tp = new TextPaint(TextPaint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
tp.setColor(Color.WHITE);
tp.setTextSize(textSize);
Rect bounds = new Rect();
tp.getTextBounds(text , 0, text.length(), bounds);
StaticLayout sl = new StaticLayout(text , tp, bounds.width()+5,
Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, 1f, 0f, false);

Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(bounds.width()+5, bounds.height()+5,
                        Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp);
sl.draw(canvas);
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bmp.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[] image = stream.toByteArray();
```

Comment: you don't need canvas.save() and canvas.restore() because you are not doing any transformation of the canvas.